# In R, how can i replace for loops with apply functions?

Tags: r

I am trying to apply an operation which applies on each row of a dataframe. Below is the code.

```
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df$final[i] <- alignfile[alignfile$Response == df$value[i],]$Aligned
  }
```

It is basically doing the vlookup from "alignfile" data frame and making a new column with the successful vlookup of "value" column in data frame "df".

How do i replace this operation with apply family of function so that i can get rid of for loops which is making it slow.

Looking for suggestions. Please feel free for more clarifications.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `findInterval()` ? Eventually `df$final <- findInterval(df$value, alignfile$Response)` or similar.

Comment: No, i am looking to create new column which matches the value of "value" column of df with "aligned" column of alignfile. It is basically vlookup.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], i.e. edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43362794/edit Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example At the current state your question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: `alignfile$Aligned[findInterval(df$value, alignfile$Response)]` Please read the documentation of the function `findInterval()` for more information.

Comment: Here is an example: `SLclass <- data.frame(SL=c(3,4,5,6,7,8), C=c("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL"));
SLclass$C[findInterval(iris$Sepal.Length, SLclass$SL)]`

Answer (score -1):

You didn't provide a reproducible example so take my answer with a grain of salt,
I think you don't need to use a for loop at all in this case (as in most cases with R) and neither an apply function. I think this problem could be easily solved with an ifelse in the following way:

```
df$final <- ifelse(alignfile$Response==df$value, 1, 0)
```

this will put a one in the `final` column of the `df` dataframe if the value in the current cell of the `alignfile$Response` column is equal to the value of the current cell in the `df$value` column. This assumes `alignfile` and `df` have the same number of rows (as it appears from the code you provided).

Comment: IMHO `df` and `alignfile` have different number of rows. So your `==` will not work.

Comment: IDK, it could be, but then his for loop wouldn't work even in theory since it's using the same index for `df` and `alignfile`

Comment: In a comment to the question OP wrote: "It is basically vlookup."

Comment: So you think he wants to check each row of `df` for the same value of `alignfile`? then I think it's a job for grepl

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the discussion. The problem is resolved.